definition of cycles and variabilities used in climate studies, meteorology and oceanography
The definitions of annual cycle, semi-annual cycles etc.. and variabilities such as annual, inter-annual, intra-annual are so fluid and confusing. Let me explain.
Annual cycle is defined as any repetition that occurs with the period of one year. Take the data of multiple years, find the mean state and subtract each years to get the anomalies, or just filter the data in 300-400 days to see the variations occurring in each year.
Both are different approach, so the terminology used for the output of each should be different. In the second approach, are we finding the annual variability, or is it inter-annual. In the first approach, are we comparing year to year, or the strength  of the cycle within the year.
I just want to properly understand what is what.

Welcome to ES! This is a forum, so please, place a question rather than make any reasoning. Aside of it, the way it is calculated is different but it is the same concept. Temperatures? They are changing during the years and attending to just a year, cycle cannot be seen. As soon as you repeat the process during more years, cycle is quite noticeable. As per your reasoning... Repetition during one year doesn´t mean 1 Jan-31 Dec, finally is annual. Calculation during years to see interannual deviations from average it is not annual variability. Place a real example to clarify it.

@DavidGarcíaBodego Thanks for the response. I'll edit the question with a real example.
